# Colorize two images in imageview with different colors

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image view with two images in it. It looks like this:

[image: Imageview with two triangles]

How you can see, my images are two triangles. Now I would like to colorize them with different colors. I tried somehting like this:

```
        Resources r = getResources();
        Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
        layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.dreieck);
        layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.dreieck_90);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

        layers[0].setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_red_light),
                PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP);
        layers[1].setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_green_light),
                PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP);
//        final LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.layer);
//
//        layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.tri1).setColorFilter(ContextCompat.
//                        getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_red_light),
//                PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP);
//        layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.tri2).setColorFilter(ContextCompat.
//                        getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_green_light),
//                PorterDuff.Mode.DST_ATOP);

//        imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

Now, both triangles will be colorized with the same color. How can I colorize them differently?